# Как разбить массив случайным образом на m элементов ?

Tags: java, массивы, случайные-числа

Подскажите пожалуйста как решить данную задачу оптимальным способом :

1. Данный массив разбить случайным образом на m  фрагментов
2. Границы фрагментов сохранить в новый массив

---

Пробовал пойти таким путем .Уперся в сохранение фрагментов в один массив

```
int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2, 22};
    Random random = new Random();
    int rnd1 = 1 + random.nextInt(7);
    int rnd2 = 3 + random.nextInt(15);
    int[] col = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, rnd1,rnd2);
    System.out.println("Массив равен " + Arrays.toString(col));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разбить массив размера `N` случайным образом на `M` фрагментов - это ни что иное как сгенерировать `M - 1` неповторяющихся случайных чисел в диапазоне `[0, N-1)`. Каждое такое случайное число - позиция, после которой делается разбиение массива.

Для исходных массивов небольшого размера прекрасно сработает "алгоритм Кнута" (?), в т.ч. потому, что он сразу генерирует *упорядоченную* последовательность случайно выбранных значений

```
// C++
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

unsigned random(unsigned n) 
{ // Случайное число в диапазоне [0, n)
  return std::rand() % n;
}

int main() 
{
  std::vector<int> arr = { 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2, 22 };
  const unsigned N = arr.size(), M = 5;

  unsigned i = 0, n = N - 1, n_splits = M - 1;

  std::cout << "[ ";
  for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  {
    std::cout << arr[i] << " ";

    // Делаем в этом промежутке разрез с вероятностью
    // 
    //       осталось сделать разрезов       n_splits
    //    -------------------------------- = --------
    //    осталось просмотреть промежутков    n - i
    //
    if (random(n - i) < n_splits)
    {
      std::cout << "][ ";
      --n_splits;
    }
  }
  std::cout << arr[i] << " ]";
}
```

Получаем

```
[ 1 2 3 5 6 ][ 7 8 ][ 9 0 ][ 5 6 7 8 9 2 ][ 22 ]
```